# Assigning arrays as values for a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have a dat file with different data. The file has different numbers arranged in 7 columns seperated with two whitespaces. Is it possible to read and extract the data for each column and assign the data to a key in a dictionary, using arrays. Is it possible to assign numpy arrays as values for a key in a dictionary?

The dat.file have numbers like this:

```
 1  -0.8  92.3  2.8  150  0  0 
 2  -0.7  99.3  1.9  140  0  0 
 3  -0.3  96.4  2.5  120  0  0 
 4  -0.3  95.0  3.1  130  0  0 
 5  -0.8  95.7  3.1  130  0  0 
 6  -0.5  95.0  2.1  120  0  0 
 7  -0.7  90.9  3.6  110  0  0 
 8  -0.6  85.7  2.6  80  0  0 
 9  -0.7  85.7  3.1  60  0  0 
 10  -1.2  85.6  3.6  50  0  8
```

I first read all the lines, then I split the values with whitespace as seperator, for each line. I tried to assign the values in each column to the corresponding key in the dictionary, but this does not work. I think I have to put the values in an array and then put the array in the dictionary in some way?

```
def read_data(filename):
    infile = open(filename, 'r')

for line in infile.readlines():
    data = {'hour': None, 'temperature': None, 'humidity':
            None, 'wind_speed':
            None, 'wind_direction':
            None, 'direct_flux': None, 'diffuse_flux': None}
    lines = line.split()

    data['hour'] = lines[0]
    data['temperature'] = lines[1]
    data['humidity'] = lines[2]
    data['wind_speed'] = lines[3]
    data['wind_direction'] = lines[4]
    data['direct_flux'] = lines[5]
    data['diffuse_flux'] = lines[6]
return data
```

Comment: try reading the file and then [transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

Comment: please show what you try, and example  of the file

Comment: Short answer yes, long answer depends on your code and the format of the data. Assuming that the data is regular and formatted consistently then yes it can be parsed and creating a dict or numpy array is trivial

Comment: Please give an example dat file containing the data you want to extract and the correlating dictionary you are expecting.

Comment: Doesn't any of the answers satisfies you? If this is the case could you explain a bit more what you need? :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I realized numpy arrays are a specific scientific data structure. I have not used them but assume converting the below lists (and its append operation) into numpy arrays is trivial.

You are correct. A dictionary holds (key, value) pairs. An entry of the form (key, value, value, ..., value) is not acceptable. Using a list() as the value (as you suggested) is a solution. Note now that the index corresponds to the line number the data was in.

```
data = {'hour': None, 'temperature': None, 'humidity':
        None, 'wind_speed':
        None, 'wind_direction':
        None, 'direct_flux': None, 'diffuse_flux': None}

# For each key, initialize a list as its value.
for key in data:
  data[key] = list()

for line in infile.readlines():
  lines = line.split()

  # we simply append into the list this key references.
  data['hour'].append(lines[0])
  data['temperature'].append(lines[1])
  data['humidity'].append(lines[2])
  data['wind_speed'].append(lines[3])
  data['wind_direction'].append(lines[4])
  data['direct_flux'].append(lines[5])
  data['diffuse_flux'].append(lines[6])
return data
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I got right what you are asking for, but I'll try to answer.

I guess you want to load those tabulated data in a way you can easily work with, and making use of `numpy`'s functionality.

Then, I think you have two options.

#### Using PANDAS

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (here the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)) is a *really complete* package that uses numpy to let you work with **labelled** data (so that columns and rows have a name, and not only a positional index)

using pandas the idea would be to do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.tab', sep="  ", index_col=0, header=None,
            names=['hour', 'temp', 'hum', 'w_speed', 'w_direction',
                   'direct_flux','diffuse_flux'])
df

      temp   hum  w_speed  w_direction  direct_flux  diffuse_flux
hour                                                             
1     -0.8  92.3      2.8          150            0             0
2     -0.7  99.3      1.9          140            0             0
3     -0.3  96.4      2.5          120            0             0
4     -0.3  95.0      3.1          130            0             0
5     -0.8  95.7      3.1          130            0             0
6     -0.5  95.0      2.1          120            0             0
7     -0.7  90.9      3.6          110            0             0
8     -0.6  85.7      2.6           80            0             0
9     -0.7  85.7      3.1           60            0             0
10    -1.2  85.6      3.6           50            0             8
```

Or, if you have the column names as the first row of the file simply:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.tab', sep="  ", index_col=0)
```

If you haven't heard of this library and you are managing this kind of data, I think it is really worthwhile to give it a close look.

#### Using only Numpy

If you don't need to do much with those data, or won't do it again or whatever, getting Pandas may be a bit too much...

In any case, you can always read the tabulated file from numpy

```
import numpy as np
array = np.loadtxt("data.tab", delimiter=" ")
```

It will ignore comment lines (by default lines with `#`) and you can also skip the first row and so on.

Now you'll have all the data on `array`, and you can access it slicing and indexing. If you want to have labelled categories (and you don't like the first option), you can build your dictionary of arrays following the last snippet of code by:

```
data = {}
headers = ['hour', 'temp', 'hum', 'w_speed', 'w_direction', 'direct_flux', 
           'diffuse_flux']
for i in xrange(len(headers)):
    data[header[i]] = array[:,i]
```